# MySQL Fetch Array echos blank result from database

Tags: php, mysqli

When trying to echo out the result of a user's initials from a database and display it to them. The problem is it only displays "Welcome, " instead of "Welcome, (user's initials)".

Below is my code in my index.php.

version1:

```
<?php 

$getting = mysql_query("
SELECT `initials` FROM `username` 
WHERE `pass` = '".$_SESSION['userName']."'
"); 

$result = mysql_fetch_array($getting); 

echo "Welcome, " . $result; 

?> 

create table username
(
    UserNameID int auto_increment primary key,
    userName varchar(100) not null,
    pass varchar(100) not null,
    initials varchar(20) not null
);

insert username (userName,pass,initials) values ('sb','bailey101','SB'),('cb','test','CB');
```

Update: I deleted the `$result = mysql_fetch_array($getting);` and then changed `echo "Welcome, " . $result;` to `echo "Welcome, " . $getting;`. I then get "Welcome, Resource id #6". How do I solve this?

**Goal:**

`mysqli` returning result set of username rows where pass = parameter passed. Use first row of that to show initials of user.

Note ignore 2nd and after rows this is just a test.

Comment: This database structure doesn't really seem to make sense. Have you verified that you get the right result when you run the query manually?

Comment: Why are you searching on pass(word)? Your image was expected from what you wrote

Comment: @AsConfused, this is just something temporary that I did. It's not actually in production yet, so it will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query result will be returned as an array (hence `mysql_fetch_array()`). Since `echo` isn't capable of printing array data, it simply doesn't print anything.

The first (and in this case only) result from your SQL query will be in `$result[0][0]`. Thus your PHP should be:

```
              <?php 

                $getting = mysql_query("SELECT `initials` FROM `username` WHERE `pass` = '".$_SESSION['userName']."'");
                $result = mysql_fetch_array($getting);

                echo "Welcome, " . $result[0][0]; 



              ?>
```

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($result)`?

Comment: When I put that below `echo "Welcome, " . $result[0][0];`, nothing happens, still the same problem.

Comment: Right. But what's the output of `print_r($result)`?

Comment: So you mean if I save my code like this?: <?php 

                $getting = mysql_query("SELECT `initials` FROM `username` WHERE `pass` = '".$_SESSION['userName']."'");
                $result = mysql_fetch_array($getting);

                echo "Welcome, " . $result[0][0]; 
print_r($result); 


              ?>

Comment: Yeah. What is printed on the page after "Welcome, "?

Comment: Literally nothing. It's just blank. It says "Welcome, ". I think it might be a problem with the MySQL query, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you show some sample data for Kitty and tell em what you are typing before submit

Comment: Yeah, that's an issue with the query. I'd start by taking a look at your database connection code.

Comment: Show the create table stmt and a few rows of users

Comment: @DrewPierce, does this help? http://i.imgur.com/5mWYPYg.png and http://i.imgur.com/VO8S3Ol.png. If not, let me know what you need. I'm still learning all of this stuff, so bear with me.

Comment: Wait-so did you really want `pass` to `=$_SESSION['userName']`?

Comment: Yeah kitty that was some confusion before seen in comments. His answer was he is new and just testing concepts

Comment: Thanks guys for the help but I kind of fixed it (temporary solution).